# Does every n-torus admit a semi-Riemannian metric?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

I know every smooth manifold admits a Riemannian metric, and I think I can state that a Riemannian metric is a semi-Riemannian metric,right? The former being just a special case of the later, so the answer should be yes. **Is this reasoning correct? Otherwise how do I prove it?**

Comment: Yes, that sounds right.

Comment: If you are at the level of understanding what a Riemannian metric is, I'm sure you can prove that any Riemannian metric is a semi-Riemannian metric—this amounts to showing (or citing) that a positive definite bilinear form is nondegenerate. (I hope that didn't sound condescending; I meant it to be encouraging.)

Comment: @pancini Thanks, yes I am just getting started,  why should I prove that, doesn't it suffice to say that by just looking at the definitions, A riemannian metric is positive definite while a semi-riemmania metric that condition is dropped, therefore the implication should be obvious, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yeah that's all there is to it. The only thing that potentially needs justification is that positive-definite$\implies$non-degenerate, but that's quite immediate from the usual definitions.

Answer (score 2):

Your reasoning is correct.
Here is a proof that directly addresses the title of your question.

The $n$-dimensional torus $\Bbb T^n$ admits semi-Riemannian metrics of any signature $(k,n-k)$.
Indeed, its cotangent bundle $T^*(\Bbb T^n)$ is trivial.
Let $\{\alpha^1,\ldots,\alpha^n\}$ be a global trivialisation.
Then $g_k = -\sum_{j=1}^k \alpha^j\otimes \alpha^j + \sum_{j=k+1}^n \alpha^j\otimes \alpha^j$ is a semi-Riemannian metric of signature $(k,n-k)$ for any $k\in \{0,\ldots,n\}$.

Comment: I was about to ask if indeed any signature was possible. So I guess this is the proof, but what is a global trivialization?

Comment: and what does it mean that the cotangent bundle is trivial?

Comment: @some_math_guy A vector bundle $E$ of rank $r$ over a manifold $M$ is trivial (or trivialisable) if there exists a vector bundle isomorphism $E\simeq M\times \Bbb R^r$. A trivialisation is such a vector bundle isomorphism, or equivalently, the data of $r$ global sections that are everywhere linearly independent. This is a basic differential topology / geometry concept. You should try to learn about this before digging into more complicated things such as semi-Riemannian geometry!

Comment: Sorry if this seems too  basic, vector bundle were practically only defined in my diff geo course and are part of another more advanced course that I have not taken yet but I am reading about it. Unfortunately the day only has 24 hours. Now in your proof I don't undersant if your are proving that the cotangent bundle of the n-dim torus is trivial or you are just using. It looks to me that you are using it as a known fact, otherwise why would a trivialization exist right?

Comment: So you start by stating this fact, I think, write the trivialization, but then why is the basis of the cotangent space given by these isomorphisms? and not by the usual differentials of the coordinate functions: $dx^1,...dx^n$?

Comment: @some_math_guy Don't be sorry for what you don't know, you're not responsible for that. I didn't mean to sound rude, sorry if that seemed the case.// I am just using that it is a trivial bundle, and I pick any trivialisation: of course, you can choose $\{dx^1,\ldots,dx^n\}$ (in fact, their projection by the quotient map) if you want. The point is that you can extend this proof for any manifold that is parallelisable (ie that has trivial (co-)tangent bundle, and they might not have "canonical" trivialisations.

Comment: I guess there are two things that I need to clarify 1) Why are $dx^i$ isomorphisms?. So they are  covectors , then they linear functionals from the tangent space at a point to R, correct? so they are by definition linear and  what else I guess I am only missing bijectivity, how do I prove that?.... 2) that the cotangent bundle of the n-torus is trivial...know where I can  see a proof of this last thing?

Comment: @some_math_guy 1) They are not individually isomorphisms. But the map $(p,\sum_i \lambda_i dx^i) \mapsto (p,\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$ is a vector bundle isomorphism between $T^*\Bbb T^n$ and $\Bbb T^n \times \Bbb R^n$. A global trivialisation is equivalent to the choice of a global (co)-frame. 2) Just look for the key words "torus trivial (co-)tangent bundle", or prove it yourself as an instructive exercise

Comment: @some_math_guy You are missing the whole point here, so I suggest you read a bit about (co-)tangent bundles, trivialisations, for instance in John Lee's introduction to differentiable manifolds. Everything will be there